# How much does water cool in 1 second

Tags: physics

I'm wondering if I've done my calculations correctly because the units I get are really weird...

So.. I'm calculating how much the temperature change in $1$ second if the temperature difference is $30$ kelvins and the cubic container ($10$ cm $\times 10$ cm $\times 10$ cm) made of glass is filled with water.

I've calculated that current heat density is 8700 watt, I've got mass by multiplying volume with density of water (1 kilogram) and specific heat of water is $4181$ J kg$^{-1}$ K$^{-1}$.

The result I get is $0.02$ m$^2$ K$^{-1}$. Now the number I kinda get but the units I don't. I really could use your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, I used j=Q/t x S=λ x ΔT/l. Am I even on the right path?

Comment: It sounds like you want the power removed over a $\Delta T = 30\ \mathrm{K}$ . Is this from convection ($q = h A \Delta T$), or conduction ($q = k A \Delta T$)? Or are you just interested in the thermodynamics ($q = V \rho c_p \Delta T$)?

Comment: I'm intrested in thermal conductivity but I'm not sure that the units i get are valid. I was expecting kelvins since I'm looking for ΔT but i guess its different for thermal conductivity.